# Cortar laterais das imagens de um slider full width

Tags: slider

Como cortar laterias das imagens de um slider jquery full width após atingir uma certa largura do dispositivo do visitante? Seria com css? Ou Javascript?

Comment: Olá, para ter essa responsividade e ser tão dinâmico assim seria melhor através do javascript. Porém você precisa postar seu código para que possamos te ajudar.